# how can use disqus to login in my mobile app?

Tags: flutter, authentication, logout, disqus

Is it possible to use the Disqus login system to login to my mobile App like it happens with Google, Facebook, Twitter ?

I'd like to let my users login to my mobile App using Disqus accounts.

I can't find any documentation.

Comment: this might be helpful:
https://disqus.com/api/docs/

Comment: have you any example ? i don't find any solution